# Error: package com.lapism.searchview.view does not exist

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, package, searchview

I have used searchview in my project with dependency *compile 'com.lapism:searchview:3.0.2'* in build.gradle file. But while I'm trying run the application I'm getting an error

1. Error: package com.lapism.searchview.view does not exist
2. Error:
   cannot find symbol class SearchView
3. Error:Execution failed for task
   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

   > *My current android version is 2.1*

### My Build.gradle File:

```
     buildscript {
     repositories 
      {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }

     dependencies
     {
     classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'}
     }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

      android {
      compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

     defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true
      applicationId "pingo.betnek.mobigrab"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 15
      versionCode 2
      versionName "1.1"
          }
          dexOptions
        {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
         }

    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
       }
      }
         repositories {
          jcenter()
          mavenCentral()
          maven {
          url "https://jitpack.io"
            }
          maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            }
    dependencies
    {
        provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile files('libs/activation.jar')
        compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
        compile files('libs/mail.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.lapism:searchview:3.0.2'
        compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.7'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar')
            {
    transitive = true;
             }

    }
```

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild the project? Did you insert that line in the correct Gradle file? (there are 2)

Comment: yes @Vucko i have done cleaning and rebuilding *Infinite* times. Infact on rebuilding i am getting this error.
I have added this Dependency in my build.gradle file 'compile 'com.lapism:searchview:3.0.2'

Comment: What build.gradle did you add it to? The one for Module:app or the Project one? It's supposed to be in Module:app. Check for typos in the compile line. After all, post your build gradle in the edited question please.

Comment: Yes in build.gradle(Module:app) @Vucko

Comment: Bloody hell, I can see no reason why this should fail. Did you try Syncing Project with gradle files? Little button left of AVD Manager in Android studio.

Comment: Yes @Vucko Syncing is successful, yields no error

Comment: And yet this error still persists? How is that possible, gradle should've downloaded the library!

Answer (score 0):

Show us your code usage..

In any case, change `com.lapism.searchview.view.SearchView` to `com.lapism.searchview.SearchView`, or just remove the imports and let Android Studio re-import them with the correct namings.

It has been refactored since 2.3 or whatever version..